# Удаление кнопок по времени

Tags: c#, wpf

День добрый, был бы признателен, если бы подсказали как удалять кнопки и ставить на их место соседнюю по наступлению времени.

Исходное
[image]
Допустим наступило 7 утра и вот такое желательно должно получиться
 [image]

Comment: Просто используйте WrapPanel, он переместит элементы за вас

Comment: Спасибо, а как удалить обьект по времени?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Честно, не уверен в данном примере, чисто мои наброски.
Хотел сделать так, что бы каждый элемент в коллекции был одним независимым объектом, который имеет свое время жизни. Естественно все по правилам MVVM.

И так, для начала нам нужен сам объект. Что в нем должно быть?

1. Имя.
2. Время жизни.
3. Время окончания.
4. Оставшееся время.
5. Таймер "жизни".
6. Таймер тика.

В итоге я сделал такой класс:

```
public class TimerViewModel : VM
{
    public TimerViewModel(string name, TimeSpan time)
    {
        Name = name;
        Time = time;
        End = DateTime.Now.Add(Time);

        StartTimer();
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Time { get; set; }
    public DateTime End { get; set; }
    private TimeSpan _timeLeft;
    public TimeSpan TimeLeft
    {
        get => _timeLeft;
        set
        {
            _timeLeft = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public event Action<TimerViewModel> Ended;
    private DispatcherTimer _deleteTimer;
    private DispatcherTimer _updateTimer;

    private void StartTimer()
    {
        _deleteTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        _updateTimer = new DispatcherTimer();

        _deleteTimer.Interval = End - DateTime.Now;
        _updateTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);

        _deleteTimer.Tick += DeleteTimerOnTick;
        _updateTimer.Tick += UpdateTimerOnTick;

        _deleteTimer.Start();
        _updateTimer.Start();
    }

    private void UpdateTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TimeLeft = End - DateTime.Now;
    }

    private void DeleteTimerOnTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        _deleteTimer.Stop();
        _updateTimer.Stop();
        Ended?.Invoke(this);
    }
}
```

Данный класс наследует стандартный INotifyPropertyChanged (для отлавливание изменений в UI). Суть довольно проста:

1. Создаем необходимые свойства и event, который послужит нам для оповещении главной VM об необходимости удалить элемент.
2. Через конструктор задаем необходимые свойства (для удобства), подсчитываем время завершения, а также запускаем таймеры.
3. В методе запуска таймеров инициализируем два таймера (один тикает раз в секунду, другой равен жизни объекта), подписываем их на свои обработчики (у того, что секунду тикает - просто обновляем свойство с оставшимся временем, а у основного - останавливаем таймер и оповещаем event). Ну и запускаем все это чудо.

Хорошо, у нас теперь есть VM объекта. Осталось сделать основную VM, заполнить ее и сделать View.

Основная ViewModel, что от нее требуется?

1. Коллекция с нашими таймерами.
2. При добавление/удаление элемента мы должны подписаться на его event удаления.
3. Метод самого удаления.

Ну что, попробуем:

```
public class MainViewModel : VM
{
    public MainViewModel()
    {
        Timers = new ObservableCollection<TimerViewModel>();
        Timers.CollectionChanged += TimersOnCollectionChanged;

        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 1", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 2", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 3", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 4", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 5", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(25)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 6", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 7", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(35)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 8", TimeSpan.FromSeconds(35)));
        Timers.Add(new TimerViewModel("Таймер 9", TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30)));
    }


    public ObservableCollection<TimerViewModel> Timers { get; set; }

    private void TimersOnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.NewItems != null)
        {
            foreach (TimerViewModel newItem in e.NewItems)
            {
                newItem.Ended += DeleteOldItemsEvent;
            }
        }

        if (e.OldItems != null)
        {
            foreach (TimerViewModel newItem in e.OldItems)
            {
                newItem.Ended -= DeleteOldItemsEvent;
            }
        }
    }

    private void DeleteOldItemsEvent(TimerViewModel obj) => Timers.Remove(obj);

}
```

Что тут происходит:

1. Создаем свойство нашей ObservableCollection.
2. В конструкторе инициализируем коллекцию, заполняем ее, а также подписываемся на событие CollectionChanged (что бы знать об добавление/удаление объектов в ней).
3. Реализуем обработчик события CollectionChanged. В нем мы проверяем, если есть старый/новый объект/объекты, то подписываемся или отписываемся от события удаления.
4. Реализуем метод удаления, тут просто удаляем из коллекции переданный event'ом объект.

Ну что, осталась View. Для такого вида, который хотите вы - стоит использовать WrapPanel, а из за того, что мы динамически создаем объекты - стоит использовать ItemsControl. Тут объяснять особо не буду, XAML в целом получился такой:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Timers}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <WrapPanel />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" Width="70" Height="70" Margin="5">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                        <RowDefinition />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <StackPanel Margin="3">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontWeight="Medium"/>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding TimeLeft, StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="#FFDADADA" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding End, StringFormat=\{0:hh\\:mm\\:ss\}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Ну что, задаем DataContext и радуемся результатом:

[image: Result]

По сути... Все это можно заменить на один таймер в MainViewModel, который будет раз в секунду тикать и к нему уже привязать основной таймер текущего времени, обновление и др. Я лишь показал один из возможных вариантов.

В общем удачи в программирование ;-)

Comment: А таймер из какого пространства имен используется? Их несколько разных и не все вызывают события в контексте GUI

Comment: @АндрейNOP Используется `System.Timers`. За основу взял данный [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/834989/220553). Сами таймеры я обычно не использую, как по мне лучше цикл в async методе, но что то в данном примере было лень все это реализовывать )

Comment: Вот, нашел: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/696486/218063 Во избежание проблем надо использовать `System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer`

Comment: @АндрейNOP Хм, спасибо. Тогда получается не нужен Dispose, достаточно их остановить, да и BeginInvoke тоже становится лишним. Переделаю пожалуй ответ.

Comment: Ну т.е. можно и `System.Timers.Timer` использовать, но придется обновлять свойства внутри `UpdateTimerOnElapsed` (и `DeleteTimerOnElapsed`?) через тот же `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke`

Comment: @EvgeniyZ а что за класс VM? TimerViewModel : "VM"

Comment: @ВикторПрокопенко Это базовый класс, который реализует INotifyPropertyChanged. Я обычно создаю public класс с названием VM и наследую его от INotifyPropertyChanged, далее сама студия мне генерирует все необходимое. Вы его можете также найти в другом моем ответе, например [этом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/832616/Обращение-к-чекнутым-чекбоксам/833104#833104).