# Команда удаления ViewModel и соответствующего ей экземпляра класса из слоя данных

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpf-commands

Есть 2 вьюмодели, основная и вьюмодель, которая соответствует созданной коллекции

**Основная вьюмодель - MainVM**. В ней есть команда, имитирующая логику получения, создания и добавления вьюмодели для данной коллекции, а так же добавление полученной коллекции в класс модели данных для последующей работы с ней.

```
public class MainVM : Notify
    {
        public ObservableCollection<CollectionVM> CollectionsVM { get; }

        public ICommand AddSampleCollectionCommand { get; }

        private Collections _collections;

        public MainVM()
        {
            _collections = new Collections();
            CollectionsVM = new ObservableCollection<CollectionVM>();
            AddSampleCollection = new RelayCommand(AddSampleCollection);
        }

        private void AddSampleCollection()
        {
            var collection = new List<SimpleType>();
            var vmForCollection = new CollectionVM()
            {
                Title = "Test title"
            };

            _collections.Add(collection);
            CollectinsVM.Add(_collectinsVM);
        }
    }
```

**Вьюмодель коллекции - CollectionVM**

```
public class CollectionVM : Notify
    {
        public string Title { get; }

        //Проблема в реализации этой команды.
        public ICommand DeleteCommand { get; }
    }
```

**Класс для хранения коллекций - Collections**. Я не стал копировать его полностью, а описал его структуру кратко.

```
public class Collections
    {
        private List<List<SimpleType>> _collestions;

        public void Add(List<SimpleType> item) => _collestions.Add(item);
        public void Delete(List<SimpleType> item) => _collestions.Remove(item);
    }
```

Сама разметка xaml имеет примерно такой вид. Для отображения вьюмоделей я взял ItemsControl (Мне нужно просто отображать элементы, выделять и т.д их не нужно, по этому и взял его)

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="CollectionsList"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding CollectionsVM}"
              ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CollectionDataTemplate}"
              BorderThickness="0">
</ItemsControl>
```

Ну и xaml ДатаТемплейта

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="CollectionDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}"/>
            <Button x:Name="DeleteButton"
                    Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"/>
        </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Проблема следующая, мне нужно по клику кнопки DeleteButton удалять соответствующую вьюмодель и экземпляр коллекции из класса Collections.
Т.к между вьюмоделью и нужным экземпляром класса нету никакой связи, я не понимаю как реализовать удаление и того и другого. Думал добавить во вьюмодель коллекции свойство со ссылкой на нужный экземпляр коллекции, но мне сказали, что так лучше не делать. 
Подскажите как это грамотно реализовать и возможно что-то полностью переделать в коде выше. Спасибо

Comment: У вас по сути 3 варианта. 1. Передать ссылку в нужный VM на тот, где у вас нужная команда/действие (`... new CollectionVM(this);`). Я не знаю почему вам говорят, что это не правильно, вполне стандартное решение. 2. В `CollectionVM` реализовать событие, которое будет оповещать о том, что объект надо удалить. При инициализации нового объекта этой VM подписываетесь и выполняете нужные действия. 3. Сделать команду удаления на слой выше (вытащить из `CollectionVM`) и привязать ее через `RelativeSource`(`FindAncestor`) в XAML.

Comment: Вспомогательные ссылки: Вариант 2 - один из моих старых [ответов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836187/220553). В нем я по таймеру вызывал событие на удаление. Вариант 3 - например этот [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/724594/220553).

Comment: В общем сделаю свойство с ссылкой, спасибо