# Правильно ли я реализовал MVVM и нужен ли он тут вообще

Tags: c#, mvvm, шаблоны-проектирования

Суть приложения, брать с сайта название фильма, закачивать картинки по названию, и устанавливать их на задний фон с названием фильма.

У меня проблема в том, что я не понимаю как правильно сделать, обновление `view` должно же происходить во `viewmodel` классе?!.

Но у меня стоит таймер в 5 секунд, который каждые 5 секунд обновляет картинку и название(берет это все из `List`)

И получается так, что 2 переменные `CurrentFilmName`,`CurrentFilmPicture` находятся в классе `viewmodel`. И чтобы установить в них значения, мне нужно сделать их статичными, либо передать класс в конструктор и с ним уже работать.

Как мне сделать правильно? Перекинуть метод таймера в класс `viewmodel`? Передать `viewmodel` в класс таймера? Или класс таймера, реализовать интерфейс `INotifyPropertyChanged` и из него, обновлять данные.

Main

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            VM viewmodel = new VM();
            DataContext = viewmodel;
            new TimerMain(viewmodel).StartScrollTimer();
        } 
    }
```

ViewModel

```
class VM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }

        private string _filmname;
        public string CurrentFilmName
        {
            get => _filmname;
            set
            {
                _filmname = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string _picturepath;
        public string CurrentPicturePath
        {
            get => _picturepath;
            set
            {
                _picturepath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

Model(Таймер)

```
 class TimerMain
    {
        private Images images = new Images();
        private List<Classes.Image> listimages = new List<Classes.Image>();
        private int numbertick = 0;
        private VM viewmodel;

        public TimerMain(VM viewmodel)
        {
            this.viewmodel = viewmodel;
        }

        public void StartScrollTimer()
        {
            images.TakeImage += (Classes.Image img) => listimages.Add(img);
            // Подписываемся на событие, когда скачивается картинка, и добавляем в массив Объектов Image(В нем хранится название, и ссылка на файл картинки)
            // Запускаем парсинг фильмов, он парсит с сайта название фильма и ищет ему картинку, при успешном нахождении, скачивает, и уведомляет о новом, созданном Image
            _ = Task.Run(async () => await images.ParsFilmsAndDownload());


            DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
            timer.Tick += new EventHandler(async (object obj, EventArgs e) =>
            {

                while (listimages.Count < numbertick + 1)
                    await Task.Delay(25);


                try
                {
                    viewmodel.CurrentFilmName = listimages[numbertick].FilmName;
                    viewmodel.CurrentPicturePath = listimages[numbertick].FilmPicture;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    viewmodel.CurrentFilmName = listimages[numbertick].FilmName;
                    viewmodel.CurrentPicturePath = listimages[numbertick = numbertick == 4 ? 0 : numbertick + 1].FilmPicture;
                }

                numbertick = numbertick == 4 ? 0 : numbertick + 1;
            });

            timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);
            timer.Start();
        }
    }
```

Сколько статей и видео не пересматривал, до конца не пойму, как правильнее, решил у вас спросить. Пока мне кажется правильной идея, реализовать `TimerMain : INotifyPropertyChanged` там сделать переменные, и обновить от туда(но тогда не соответствую паттерну, viewmodel должен же обновлять view).

---

Изменения:

VMFilms

```
 class VMFilms : INPC
    {
        private string filmName;
        public string CurrentFilmName
        {
            get => filmName;
            set
            {
                filmName = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        private string picturePath;
        public string CurrentPicturePath
        {
            get => picturePath;
            set
            {
                picturePath = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
    }
```

INPC

```
class INPC : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        public void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string prop = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Так, по порядку: `DataContext = viewmodel` - это не очень правильно, ибо View не должно быть ответственно за создание других слоев ([читаем](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/562586/220553)). `INotifyPropertyChanged` - вынесите в отдельный класс, который будет ответственен только за реализацию INPC, от него дальше и наследуйтесь. Именования: в C# принято писать каждое слово с заглавной буквы (`SomeValue`), если это приватное значение, то первая буква идет маленькой, но остальные по-прежнему с заглавной (`someValue`), то есть всякие `filmname` должны быть `filmName`.

Comment: Далее, почему у вас VM (главная VM, задача которой объединить все в одно целое) вдруг ответственна за имена фильмов? Сделайте отдельный класс `FilmViewModel` и у него свойство `Name` и `PicturePath`, в `VM` инициализируйте и запускайте логику по обновлению. Далее, `new TimerMain(viewmodel).StartScrollTimer();` - MVVM, это разделение всего на мало связанные слои, где View отдельный слой, который не знает что-либо про M и VM, как и Model не знает что-либо про VM и V. Почему вдруг у вас основным классом стал M слой? Пусть VM все собирает, инициализирует его и обращается к нужным объектам.

Comment: Представьте, что Model, это некий отдельный офис в другом городе, вы ему посылаете запрос в виде письма/звонка/факса, а он вам обратно нужные данные. То есть он и знать не знает что-либо про вас, вот также и тут, у вас есть класс, которому вы шлете команды, а он отдает ответ. Например "данные обновились" - это событие, на которое в VM слое был подписан слушатель и который уже эти данные заносит куда ему надо, а View видит, что данные обновились (INPC) и обновляет интерфейс. Помниться я делал с таймерами нечто [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836187), посмотрите, будет полезно.

Comment: Я первые правки внес, но остальное что-то понять не могу. Я создал класс, в котором реализовал `INotifyPropertyChanged`, далее для всех `VM` унаследовал его. + У меня появилась `VMFilms` с `FilmName` и `FilmPicture`. И тут я встал. Как мне это сделать `в VM инициализируйте и запускайте логику по обновлению`. Логика по обновлению в самих `FilmName, FilmPicture`. Дальше идет проблема у меня с `TimerMain`, Вы предлагаете его инициализировать в `VM` и все, или его логику перенести в `VMFilms`? И последний вопрос, как мне дать переменные из `VMFilms` в `Main Timer`, Наследование? Инициализация?

Comment: Для наглядности, что я навоял, обновил вопрос

Comment: `как мне дать переменные из VMFilms в Main Timer` - еще раз прочитайте мои комментарии и поймите, что "MVVM - это подход программирования, когда код делят на мало связанные друг с другом слои". У вас не должен Model слой знать чего либо про ViewModel. Если для его работы требуется некое значение, то делаете метод, который принимает это значение, но не VM слой целиком (прим: `GetFilm(id: 154)`). По поводу таймера - вот у вас есть слой Model - ваши данные, есть `ViewModel` - слой, который общается с M подготавливает данные для V. Где должны быть обновления данных? Наверно в M слое?

Comment: Я бы сделал так: `FilmModel` - некий класс, который содержит в себе данные фильма, в нем нужные свойства и запущенный таймер (или другой слушатель), по его "тику" будет вызываться событие (`event`), назовем его к примеру `DataUpdated`, это событие будет передавать "слушателям" новые данные (новая картинка, название итд), то есть `DataUpdated?.Invoke(new FilmModel("Новое назване", "Новая картинка"))`. Дальше в главной VM (обычно `MainViewModel`), я бы проинициализировал `FilmModel` как приватное свойство, подписался бы на событие и по его вызову реализовал VM свойство фильма.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Давайте я вам напишу небольшой пример, который покажет как реализовать MVVM подход для чтения чего либо с сервера раз в N сек.

Для начала поймем какие вы допустили ошибки:

1. Ваше окно (View слой) строго зависим от других слоев (ViewModel и Model), также оно у вас отвечает за создание других слоев, что с точки зрения MVVM не совсем правильно, ведь MVVM, это подход проектирования, где слои слабо связаны друг с другом. То есть этого кода у вас вовсе не должно быть:

   ```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        VM viewmodel = new VM();
        DataContext = viewmodel;
        new TimerMain(viewmodel).StartScrollTimer();
    }
   ```
2. У вас Model тесно завязана на ViewModel, это неправильно и опять является нарушением MVVM, ведь Model, это отдельный слой, который делает свою задачу и отдает нужные данные наружу по требованию ViewModel, но не на оборот. Этого кода у вас быть не должно:

   ```
   new TimerMain(viewmodel).StartScrollTimer();
   ```
3. У вас все смешено в одну "кашу". Есть такая вещь, зовется SOLID, там правило SRP - единственная ответственность. Вот задайте себе вопрос, а ответственен ли класс `VM` за фильм? Он должен вообще иметь в себе методы или свойства по обработке фильма? Я думаю, нет. Так почему это не вынести в отдельный класс, который будет в себе иметь все, что нам надо?
4. У вас есть некоторые проблемы с наименованием. В C# принято именовать на понятном, английском языке все, пытаясь коротко отразить суть того или иного объекта. Ваш класс `VM` - это что? Также не забываем, что в C# используется CamelCase, где каждая начальная буква слова должна быть заглавной, а если это приватное значение, то первая буква делается в нижнем регистре, остальные также с заглавной. То есть `filmname` -> `filmName`, `listimages` -> `listImages` и т.д..
5. Вы не совсем, верно, работаете с асинхронностью. Зачем вам `_ = Task.Run(async () => await images.ParsFilmsAndDownload());`, если можно (и даже нужно) сделать `public async Task StartScrollTimer()`? Также если это ваш метод, то почему он не возвращает данные? По названию он должен спарсить и скачать нам фильм, то есть "парсинг" подразумевает то, что мы должны получить желаемы данные. Ну и заметьте, опять проблема с именованием, почему вдруг `images` (картинки) имеет метод "скачать фильм"?

---

Так, давайте теперь напишем простенький MVVM проект, который будет брать из интернета случайную картинку и выводить ее на экран раз в N сек.

1. Напишем Model.
   Я взял первый попавшийся сайт в интернете по запросу `random image api`, `source.unsplash.com`. Нам надо для него написать модель, которая будет иметь все необходимые методы для работы с сайтом.

   ```
    public class UnsplashModel
    {
        //https://source.unsplash.com/1600x900/?nature,water

        // Читаем документацию. Клиент задается один раз на все приложение!
        // Если он должен использоваться где либо еще, то стоит создать его в другом месте и передавать как ссылку.
        private static readonly HttpClient httpClient
            = new() { BaseAddress = new("https://source.unsplash.com/") };

        public event Action<Uri> OnNewImage;

        /// <summary>
        /// Найти случайное изображение по ключевым словам и размеру.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="size">Размер нужного изображения</param>
        /// <param name="keywowrds">Ключевые слова</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="Uri"/> найденного изображения</returns>
        public async Task<Uri> SearchImageAsync(Size size, params string[] keywowrds)
        {
            try
            {
                var responseMessage = await httpClient.GetAsync($"{size}/?{string.Join(',', keywowrds)}");
                responseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                var imageUri = responseMessage.RequestMessage.RequestUri;
                OnNewImage?.Invoke(imageUri);
                return imageUri;
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Найти случайное изображение по ключевым словам и размеру по умолчанию 1920х1080.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keywowrds">Ключевые слова</param>
        /// <returns><see cref="Uri"/> найденного изображения</returns>
        public Task<Uri> SearchImageAsync(params string[] keywowrds)
            => SearchImageAsync(new(1920, 1080), keywowrds);

        /// <summary>
        /// Получает случайно изображение с указанными параметрами раз в <paramref name="delay"/> секунд.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="delay">Частота обновлений</param>
        /// <param name="size">Размер нужного изображения</param>
        /// <param name="keywowrds">Ключевые слова</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public async Task StartRandomAsync(TimeSpan delay, Size size, params string[] keywowrds)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                _ = await SearchImageAsync(size, keywowrds);
                await Task.Delay(delay);
            }
        }
    }
   ```

   Посмотрите внимательней, у нас простой класс, который выполняет свою логику и отдает наружу нужные данные. Он не ссылается на VM или что-либо еще. `Size` - это простая структура с двумя числами, не более.

   ```
    public struct Size
    {
        public Size(int width, int height)
            => (Width, Height) = (width, height);

        public int Width { get; init; }
        public int Height { get; init; }

        public override string ToString()
            => $"{Width}x{Height}";
    }
   ```
2. Делаем ViewModel изображения. Суть класса - содержать в себе необходимые данные изображения (может вес, ссылку, автора, размеры, да все что угодно, что относится именно к изображению), у меня он такой:

   ```
    public class ImageViewModel
    {
        public ImageViewModel(DateTime updateTime, Uri uri)
            => (UpdateTime, Uri) = (updateTime, uri);

        public DateTime UpdateTime { get; }
        public Uri Uri { get; }
    }
   ```

   INPC тут не нужен так, как мы не обновляем старое, а получаем новое.
3. Основная ViewModel, некий класс, который будет общаться с Model и составит нам свойства для привязки.

   ```
    public class MainViewModel : BindableBase
    {
        private readonly UnsplashModel unsplashModel;

        public MainViewModel()
        {
            unsplashModel = new();
            unsplashModel.OnNewImage += OnNewImage;
        }

        private void OnNewImage(Uri imageUri)
            => Image = new(DateTime.Now, imageUri);

        private ImageViewModel image;
        public ImageViewModel Image
        {
            get => image;
            set => SetProperty(ref image, value);
        }

        public async Task StartAsync()
            => await unsplashModel.StartRandomAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15), new(1920, 1080), "nature", "sky");
    }
   ```

   Тут уже используется INPC. Ну а логика думаю простая, понять можно без проблем. Инициализируем, подписываемся на событие, ждем, инициализируем свойство.
4. Делаем View. В нем нам надо создать нужный дизайн и указать какие свойства должны использоваться:

   ```
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Image Grid.RowSpan="2"
               Source="{Binding Image.Uri}" 
               VerticalAlignment="Center"
               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
               Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
        <Border Grid.Row="1" Padding="8 10" Background="#F4F5F5F5">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Image.UpdateTime, StringFormat='Обновлено: {0:dd.MM.yyyy в hh:mm}'}"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock Text="Ссылка на изображение:"/>
                    <TextBox IsReadOnly="True" Text="{Binding Image.Uri, Mode=OneWay}"
                         BorderThickness="0" Background="{x:Null}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
   ```
5. Отображаем окно и инициализируем ViewModel.

   - Идем в App.xaml и удаляем там `StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"`
   - Далее в `App.xaml.cs` переопределяе `OnStartup`:

     ```
       protected async override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
       {
           base.OnStartup(e);

           var viewModel = new MainViewModel();
           new MainWindow() { DataContext = viewModel }.Show();
           await viewModel.StartAsync();
       }
     ```

Собственно, на этом все, программа будет раз в 15 сек брать с сервера изображение и отображать нам его на экране

[image: Result]

Вам остается эту все понять и подстроить под себя)

Comment: Спасибо за обширный ответ, до него я попробовал все сделать как вы говорили, получилось почти так же.

Comment: Суть `MainViewModel` насколько я помню, вы говорили, объеденить все. Т.е кнопки, будут располагаться в ней, но в них уже будет связь с их моделями. Т.е `public ICommand button1 { // Действия кнопки, отправка данных, запуск метода, и если надо, получение данных с модели}` и эта кнопка будет в `MainViewModel` так получается?

Comment: @Houl А это уже зависит от вашей архитектуры, того, как вы разработаете проект. Вообще, по-хорошему, делать нечто [такое](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1278817/220553) (очень советую изучить и хотя бы попробовать такой подход). То есть у нас под каждое окно идет своя VM, под каждый контрол своя VM и так далее. Конкретно с `MainViewModel`, это, по сути, также, VM для `MainWindow`, для главного окна. Если добавляемая вами кнопка относится к нему, она ответственна за действия в этом окне, то да, ей там место.