# Выполнение кода при наступлении установленной даты и время

Tags: c#, wpf, события, datetime, уведомления

У меня есть список объектов с филдом, в котором хранится DateTime. Как сделать так, что бы при наступлении установленной даты и время в этом филде, исполнялся метод?

Comment: Если время небольшое, то можно при создании каждого объекта запускать таймер, который выполнит действие ([пример с удалением](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/836187/220553)). Если объектов много и точность не особо важна, то можно сделать один таймер/цикл, который раз в N сек/мин будет проверять объекты и запускать действие, если у тех истекло время. Ну а если время очень большое, нужна точность, то тут явно нужны сторонние компоненты, для c# есть два популярных: [Quartz.NET](https://www.quartz-scheduler.net) и [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io).

Comment: может поможет, в дополнение к пред-му комменту: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.timers.timer.elapsed?view=net-6.0

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, Спасибо большое. Реализовал для каждого объекта свой таймер. Все работает!

Answer (score -1):

ВНИМАНИЕ!!!
КАК ДЕЛАТЬ НЕ НАДО!!!

```
UInt64 wait = 1; // кол-во времени в ед.
        while (true)
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (wait <= Int32.MaxValue)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep((Int32)wait);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    wait -= Int32.MaxValue;
                    Thread.Sleep(Int32.MaxValue);
                }
            }
            DoSomeWork();
        }
```

Это таймер после запуска программы. Для твоего решения внутрь просто засунь проверку на нужную дату в if.

Но это все ерундистика и так делать не нужно. Используй планировщик.

Comment: Такого бреда я ещё не видел :)

Comment: Стараемся)))
Взял инфу с киберфорума https://www.cyberforum.ru/csharp-beginners/thread2273667.html